# Angular FB Share with no Backend

Tags: angularjs, facebook

Restriction: I only have access to upload html/css/js to the server through our client.

Im trying to share to facebook without a backend in angularjs.
So I need the meta tags. But I need to share different content based on what page you are on and I have no control over the backend. Any ideas on how to get FB to pick this up with angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this without a backend. You need something to render the templates and switch between them in order for the facebook to read different meta tags to share different messages. Apparently this used to work with FB's sharer.php but it no longer accepts your params and has been deprecated by the FB team.

Comment: Try using a service like prerender.io